# static service object becomes null

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-service

I have added a `BroadcastReceiver` in my manifest file to detect the network changes. Here is the class that extends `BroadcastReceiver`.

```
public class NetworkConnectivityReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
static FirstService firstService;
public static void initServiceObj (FirstService serviceObj) {
    if (serviceObj == null) {
        CommonUtils.printLog("service obj is null.. returing");
        return;
    }
    CommonUtils.printLog("setter called for serviceObj");
    firstService = serviceObj;

}
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (firstService == null) {
        CommonUtils.printLog("service obj is null in onreceive.. returing");
        return;
    }
    firstService.onNetworkChange();
}
}
```

I am starting a service called FirstService and in `onCreate` of that service I call the static method `initServiceObj` to init the `FirstService` obj. I see from the logs that the object is set. But when the network changes then in `onReceive`  I find the service object to be null. Why is the static variable becoming null in onReceive? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: what do you need `static FirstService firstService;` for? if you need to pass some info to your service then init your `Intent` with extras and just call `startService`

Comment: @pskink I need the service object so that whenever network changes I can call the method on that object in the service class. And I suppose it has to be static because I do not have control over the object on which "onReceive" is called.

Comment: if you need to pass some info to your service then init your `Intent` with extras and just call `startService`

Comment: @pskink the service is already up and running when I get a notification in my `BroadcastReceiver`. And I need to call a method in my service class not pass some info to it.

Comment: no, you cannot "call" a method in your service (it is not a bound service), just call `startService` instead

Comment: @pskink just to clarify this approach would have worked if `firstService ` was an object of a regular class and not a service class? why can't I do the same with services?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/106993/discussion-between-shshnk-and-pskink).

Comment: static fields are not safe, most likely your entire process was killed so the static fields are gone, try to use `static {...}` block in your receiver and do some `Log.d` calls from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably I was using the wrong approach. As suggested in the comments Now I call `startService` with an intent with a flag set, and in my on `onStartCommand` I check for that flag. If the flag is set then I simply call `onNetworkChange()`. That solved the problem for me.